# What is the meaning of "casting a blind eye"?

Tags: meaning

What do you mean by "casting a blind eye to scenes of misery around them." ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual idiom is to *[turn a blind eye](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+blind+eye)*, which means:-

> Fig. to ignore something and pretend you do not see it.
>
> The usher turned a blind eye to the little boy who sneaked into the
>   theater. How can you turn a blind eye to all those starving children?

Probably the most famous instance of this was Admiral Nelson at the [Battle of Copenhagen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Copenhagen), who is said to have disobeyed Sir Hyde Parker's order to withdraw by holding his telescope to his blind eye to look at the signals, and then claiming not to have seen them.

Comment: This was Parker's intention, as he had no idea what was happening and he wanted to give Nelson the choice of withdrawing or not.  The Royal Navy had a habit of [executing admirals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Byng) who withdrew without good reason

Comment: Turning a blind eye is a popular phrase with a meaning that is almost literal. Therefore it doesn't satisfy the definition of idiom. The figurative part is using visual blindness as a metaphor for closing one's mind or empathy. But dictionaries commonly give one of the meanings of "to see" as to grasp, or understand, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The verb [cast](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cast) is often used to mean

> to direct (a glance, attention, etc): *cast your eye over this*

To *cast a blind eye* is to *not* see something.

The phrase has a slightly ironic flavor since *casting an eye* is a deliberate act. So *casting a blind eye* suggests deliberately not seeing something that you do not want to see.

Comment: p.s. I agree with Brian Hooper that *turn a blind eye* is the more common phrase, and an ngram confirms it. That phrase also has the same deliberate quality.