# Word that means "excluding something from a calculation."

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I asked the teacher if he could [...] my attendance record from my final score.

I think *omit* sounds too light, almost like a joke. And *ignore* as thought it were an act of corruption.

Comment: Why not simply "*exclude*", as in your question title?

Comment: If you change the sentence's structure slightly, you could use *disregard* (assuming you want your attendance record excluded because it is *poor*!): "*I asked the teacher if he could disregard my attendance record when calculating my final grade*".

Comment: If he could leave out my attendance record..

Comment: related: [Is there a single word for “turn a blind eye”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217077/is-there-a-single-word-for-turn-a-blind-eye) and this answer to a different question: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/130944/44619

Comment: @Mari-LouA Great find! In particular, ***overlook*** seems particularly apt here (again assuming the attendance record is *poor*; this wouldn't work if the effect of the record would be to increase the final score).

Comment: If he could __discount__ my attendance record

Comment: I suspect you meant "as though" not "as thought"

Comment: In some contexts the word for leaving something out is "neglect", but you don't "neglect from"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like any of the others people have given in comments, you could try **except**, which, as a verb, means

> **except** *verb, transitive*
>   5. (tr) to leave out; omit; exclude [[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/except)]

It carries the connotation of making a special case for the item in question.

Comment: +1 because although I'm not sure exactly why OP says ***to omit*** is "too light" for his purposes, I think this usage of ***to except*** is definitely a bit on the "heavy" side! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about expunge?

> "Full Definition of EXPUNGE (transitive verb)
>
> 1:  to strike out, obliterate, or mark for deletion
>
> 2:  to efface completely :  destroy
>
> 3:  to eliminate (as a memory) from one's consciousness

source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expunge

Comment: Mmmm- expunge has the idea of removing something from the record completely so it cannot be seen again. The OP evidently doesn't want to delete the information from the record, just to ignore it when his final score is calculated

Answer (score 0):

It would involve rewording your sentence a bit, but you could ask him if he **factor out** your attendance record when calculating your final score.

> Phrasal verb: **Factor something in (or out)**
>
> Include (or exclude) something as a relevant element when making a decision:
>
> *When the psychological costs are factored in, a different picture will emerge.*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/factor?q=factor%20in)